# Redux ReactJS : How Components have access to the store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

for starting, i saw many questions which looks like mine on stackoverflow but i think i miss something, this is why i'm asking this question.

I have a Maincomponent in my app which add datas to my store using the action addDatas. 
This part works, i can access to my store in the context and in the children of MainComponent with this.props.
But when i go to OtherComponent (which is a basic component where i just want to show all the datas collected in MainComponent) my store seems to be empty.

Can someone tells me what i'm doing wrong and what OtherComponent should looks like for access the datas i set in the store when i was using MainComponent.

Thanks.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';    
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';    
import reducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

reducers.js

```
import { ADD_DATAS } from '../constants';

const reminder = (action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_DATAS:
      return {
        datas: action.datas,
        id: action.id
      };
    default:
      return {
        text: action.text,
        id: action.id
      };
  }

}

const reminders = (state = [], action) => {
  let reminders = null;
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_DATAS:
      reminders = [...state, reminder(action)];
      return reminders;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reminders;
```

Action.js

```
import {ADD_DATAS} from '../constants';
// ADD_DATAS = 'ADD_DATAS' in constants

export const addDatas = (text, id) => {
  const action = {
    type: ADD_DATAS,
    datas: text,
    id: id
  }
  return action;
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import RouterComponent from '../Router/RouterComponent';
import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent';
import MainComponent from './MainComponent';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
           <Sidebar />
            <Router>
              <RouterComponent>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/oth" component={OtherComponent}/>
                    <Route exact path="/main" component={MainComponent}/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={MainComponent}/>
                </Switch>
              </RouterComponent>
            </Router>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { addDatas } from '../actions'

class MainComponent extends Component {

  addDataStore(text, id){
    this.props.addDatas(text, id)
  }

  render(){
    return ( .... )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({addDatas}, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    reminders: state
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

OtherComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class OtherComponent extends Component {
    render(){
       console.log(this.props.reminders)
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        reminders: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OtherComponent);
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/sidebar.css';

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <nav className="col-2 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <div className="sidebar-logo">
          <a href="/main">
            MainComponent
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul >
          <li >
            <a href="/main" >
              MainComponent
            </a>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a href="/oth" >
              OtherComponent
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me that how you navigate to next page?

Comment: I navigate to other component with an other component which is a Sidebar. This component in my code is just above the Router component in App.js and in this sidebar i have some text like this: <a href="/oth"> text </a>

Comment: When you refresh the page then redux store become empty. So you can use this.props.history.push('/OtherComponent')

Comment: My Sidebar is outside the router component, how can i do for navigate then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Understand this we first need to understand the below snippet

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

we are passing mapStateToProps function to the connect method which we get from react-redux. So let's Understand how connect works and what it actually does

```
1. It calls your mapStateToProps function and passes the current value of (redux state/ redux store) to the function.
2. Then whatever value is returned by the mapStateToProps function after execution is passed down as props to the mainComponent(in your case).
```

So Since the child component for the main component is not having connect statement the props are not available to it.
You can make the redux state available as props by two was

```
1. Passing it down from main component as follows inside mainComponent.js render method we have
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { addDatas } from '../actions'

class MainComponent extends Component {

  addDataStore(text, id){
    this.props.addDatas(text, id)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Child1 reminders={this.props.reminders}/*can be accessed as this.props.reminders*//>
      <Child2 reminders={this.props.reminders}/*can be accessed as this.props.reminders*//>   
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({addDatas}, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    reminders: state
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

```
2.Another way to do this will be using connect Statement inside your child component as well
```

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
```

```js
 class Child1 extends Component{
 .....
 
 
 
 
 
 }



function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({addDatas}, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    reminders: state
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Child1);//need to change here must be same as className
```

Answer (score 2):

You should connect your OtherComponent to redux store as well using connect HoC.

Comment: That's true, but can you please add a code example? I don't think this will be very helpful to the OP

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect other components with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps functions as you do in MainComponents.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { addDatas } from '../actions'

class OtherComponent extends Component {
    addDataStore(text, id) {
        this.props.addDatas(text, id)
    }
    render() {
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ addDatas }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ...state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OtherComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would connect the `otherComponent` as well using `connect` HOC, in order to access the `Store`. Once you have a component connected the Store in the Hierarchy you can pass the data as props on to its children. However you do need to connect the top level component/s to `store`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class OtherComponent extends Component {
    render(){
       console.log(this.props.reminders)
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        reminders: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OtherComponent);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing but my reminders are empty when i'm doing this.
For navigating between components i'm using <a href="/oth"> go to other component </a>, is that the problem ?

Comment: Can you add the OtherComponent code, Also when you setup Routes, you should use `Link` from react-router for navigation

Comment: I can't use Link because my sidebar is outside the router component, how can i do ? (all my components are now visible above)

Answer (score 0):

Well,

my problem wasn't on my implementation of Redux but on the fact that i used href for navigate between my components.
The problem was that my Sidebar component wasn't in the Router component, then i had to save the history in the redux store and call history.push in my sidebar component with the history i saved before.

In all my components inside the router i added in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  ...
  this.props.addHistory(props.history);
}
```

addHistory add history if it doesn't already exist.
Then in my sidebar, i use the history in the store for use the push function:

```
for (var e in this.props.reminders){
  if(this.props.reminders[e].history !== undefined ){
    this.props.reminders[e].history.push('/oth');
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's the cleanest way to do this, but it works.